# OpenSSL certificate lacks key identifiers

Tags: c++, certificate, openssl, key

How do i add these sections to certificate (i am manualy building it using C++).

```
    X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
        A4:F7:38:55:8D:35:1E:1D:4D:66:55:54:A5:BE:80:25:4A:F0:68:D0
    X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
        keyid:A4:F7:38:55:8D:35:1E:1D:4D:66:55:54:A5:BE:80:25:4A:F0:68:D0
```

Curently my code builds sertificate well, except for those keys.. :/

```
static X509 * GenerateSigningCertificate(EVP_PKEY* pKey)
{
    X509 *x;
    x = X509_new(); //create x509 certificate

    X509_set_version(x, NID_X509);
    ASN1_INTEGER_set(X509_get_serialNumber(x), 0x00000000); //set serial number
    X509_gmtime_adj(X509_get_notBefore(x), 0);
    X509_gmtime_adj(X509_get_notAfter(x),(long)60*60*24*365); //1 year
    X509_set_pubkey(x, pKey); //set pub key from just generated rsa

    X509_NAME *name;

    name = X509_get_subject_name(x);

    NAME_StringField(name, "C", "LV");
    NAME_StringField(name, "CN", "Point"); //common name
    NAME_StringField(name, "O", "Point"); //organization

    X509_set_subject_name(x, name); //save name fields to certificate
    X509_set_issuer_name(x, name); //save name fields to certificate

    X509_EXTENSION *ex;
    ex = X509V3_EXT_conf_nid(NULL, NULL, NID_netscape_cert_type, "server");
    X509_add_ext(x,ex,-1);
    X509_EXTENSION_free(ex);

    ex = X509V3_EXT_conf_nid(NULL, NULL, NID_netscape_comment, "example comment extension");
    X509_add_ext(x, ex, -1);
    X509_EXTENSION_free(ex);

    ex = X509V3_EXT_conf_nid(NULL, NULL, NID_netscape_ssl_server_name, "www.lol.lv");

    X509_add_ext(x, ex, -1);
    X509_EXTENSION_free(ex);

    ex = X509V3_EXT_conf_nid(NULL, NULL, NID_basic_constraints, "critical,CA:TRUE");
    X509_add_ext(x, ex, -1);
    X509_EXTENSION_free(ex);

    X509_sign(x, pKey, EVP_sha1()); //sign x509 certificate
    return x;
}
```

Comment: FYI: anyone looking at this as sample code, this call "X509_set_version(x, NID_X509);" is wrong it should be "X509_set_version(x, 2);"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found solution - add these lines to code

```
ex = X509V3_EXT_conf_nid(NULL, NULL, NID_subject_key_identifier, "hash");
X509_add_ext(x, ex, -1);
X509_EXTENSION_free(ex);

ex = X509V3_EXT_conf_nid(NULL, NULL, NID_authority_key_identifier, "keyid:always");
X509_add_ext(x, ex, -1);
X509_EXTENSION_free(ex);
```

Comment: Just for completeness sake: this function is not part of the OpenSSL API, it comes from an [OpenSSL sample](https://www.codeblog.org/viewsrc/openssl-fips-1.1.1/demos/x509/mkcert.c).

Comment: That's odd. I could not get similar code (`.../demos/mkcert.c`) to work properly. I got a NULL `X509_EXTENSION` back from `X509V3_EXT_conf_nid`, with error "0x22073072" ("X509 V3 routines:S2I_SKEY_ID:no public key") when trying to add the SKI. And yes, the public key was set earlier via `X509_set_pubkey`).

Comment: To make it work proper, you should initialize and set context as second argument `X509V3_set_ctx(&v3ctx, issuer, subject, 0, 0, 0);` `X509V3_EXT_conf_nid(0, &v3ctx, nid, val));` http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/Error-0x22073072-when-adding-SKI-to-CA-Cert-tp48661p48662.html