# X509 certificates - maintaining certification path

Tags: python, openssl, x509

I'm working on X509 storage system for some python based program. All certificates are kept in PostgresSQL database for easy access. All working ok, when for each subject(user or CA authority) there is only one certificate. Then finding validation path is easy, as issuer field uniquely identify next certificate:

```
UserCert1(CA_cert_class1) -> CA_cert_class1(CA_cert_root) -> CA_cert_root(CA_cert_root)
```

The problems starts when some certificates are renewed due to expiration or any other reason.
Then two or more certificates have the same subject. In that case there is more than one possible certification paths.

```
UserCert1(CA_cert_class1) -> CA_cert_class1(CA_cert_root)(old)->....
                          -> CA_cert_class1(CA_cert_root)(new)->....
```

Trying each combination is not a solution. Also removing expired certificates is not a solution, as I need them to validate old digital signatures.

QUESTION: How to uniquely identify issuer cert within X509 certificate. I guess, this have something to do with X509v3 extensions. I'm not sure how to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an X509v3 extension for this.  It's the AKI (Authority Key Identifier).  This number in the child certificate should match the SKI (Subject Key Identifier) in the parent certificate.

See [RFC5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.1) for more details.  The SKI can be derived by a hash of the Public Key, or anything that generates a unique number.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. Now I have to figure it out, how to add extension in cpp with OpenSSL API.

Comment: I found nice example in cpp:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883164/openssl-certificate-lacks-key-identifiers

Answer (score 1):

Certificate Issuer and Serial Number uniquely identifies a X.509 certificate (for all conforming certificate). Even if the certificate is renewed, its serial number should be different.

X509v3 extension such as subject unique identifier is not guaranteed to exist in the certificate.

Please try the combination of Issuer and Serial Number.

Comment: Yes, that is true. But the problem is that issuer's serial number is not mentioned in subject's certificate. All I have is name field with issuer name (X500 notation).

I can guarantee existence of X509v3 extensions within any certificate, as all of them will be created by my program.

So if there will be any way to put for example issuer certificate fingerprint within subject's certificate - that would solve all my problems.

Comment: I am not a python programmer. In C, following Macro may helps you get Issuer Unique ID #define X509_issuerUID(x)   (x)->cert_info->issuerUID
 where x is a X509 * struct certificate.

Comment: Means if you can access X509 * structure in python, you can access following field.